copy files to dockerfile isn't workin, ls shows that files are there
currently I'm really blind and don't see what my issue is and I hope that a fresh pair of your eyes can help me out here.
I have following Dockerfile
ARG base_image=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime
ARG base_image_version=8.0
ARG port=80
# Use a runtime image as the base image
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime
FROM ${base_image}:${base_image_version} AS runtime
# The name of DLL which needs to be used for starting the application
ARG DLL_NAME
ENV env_dll_name=${DLL_NAME}

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the published application files
COPY --chown=$APP_UID:$APP_UID . ./

# Change ownership of the files to the dedicated user
RUN chown -R $APP_UID:$APP_UID /app

# Switch to the dedicated user
USER $APP_UID

# List the contents of the /app directory to verify the files copied
RUN ls -la /app

# List the DLL to be executed
RUN echo "DLL to execute: ${env_dll_name}"
# Expose the port that the application will listen on
EXPOSE ${port}

RUN ls -la .

# Define the entry point for the container
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "dotnet ${env_dll_name}"]

The Azure DevOps Pipeline runs follwing tasks
- script: |
    pwd
    ls -la .
    ls -la $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    ls -la $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PublishOutput

- task: Docker@2   displayName: 'Docker - Build'   inputs:
    command: build
    #containerRegistry: $(ACR_LOGIN_SERVER)
    repository: $(ACR_LOGIN_SERVER)/$(dockerImageName)
    Dockerfile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/Dockerfile'  # Path to your Dockerfile
    buildContext: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PublishOutput'
    arguments: '--progress=plain --build-arg DLL_NAME=$(project_name).dll'
    tags: |-
      $(releaseVersion)
      latest

The RUN ls -la lines shows the expected folder content.
But when the container starts up on AKS, it fails as the dll isn't found.
I have replace the entrypoint with CMD ["sh", "-c", "ls -la /app && sleep 3600"] and already see only following
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jul  8 17:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul  9 04:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  8 17:37 ..2024_07_08_17_37_44.4116578998
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jul  8 17:37 ..data -> ..2024_07_08_17_37_44.4116578998
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   23 Jul  8 17:37 appsettings.json -> ..data/appsettings.json

What I'm doing wrong?
Please help
Edit:
The dotnet build result is produced by
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: |
      **/*.csproj
      !**/*Test.csproj
      !**/*Tests.csproj
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PublishOutput'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    publishWebProjects: false
  displayName: 'dotnet - Publish Project'

Edit:
Screenshot from Docker - Build Task


where/how is the dll being generated?

the whole build is created outside and upfront the "docker build", but within the same job

How exactly do you conclude that the DLL doesn't exist?

@tripleee please see above

I have replace the entrypoint with CMD ["sh", "-c", "ls -la /app && sleep 3600"] and already see only following...


I have found the issue.
Within the deployment, a config map is created. the mountPath was pointing to the folder, instead of the file

Glad to know this. So my understanding is the image is created fine in pipeline, the issue   happens when you deploy the image to AKS, is it correct?

yeah fully correct

Thanks for quick response! Happy day! :)

Your Dockerfile exists in $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)(eg: /home/vsts/work/1/s), but the dll was built into $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PublishOutput which is different. And you specify buildContext to that directory, which typically should be same directory with Dockerfile.

Hence, after your DotNetCoreCLI@2 publish task, you can copy the dll into the working directory which Dockerfile exists:
- script: |
    pwd
    ls -la .
    cp $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PublishOutput/*.dll .

I commented repository and buildContext for Docker@2 task:
- task: Docker@2   
  displayName: 'Docker - Build'   
  inputs:
    command: build
    #containerRegistry: $(ACR_LOGIN_SERVER)
    #repository: $(ACR_LOGIN_SERVER)/$(dockerImageName)
    Dockerfile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/Dockerfile'  # Path to your Dockerfile
    #buildContext: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PublishOutput'
    arguments: '--progress=plain --build-arg DLL_NAME=$(project_name).dll'
    tags: |-
      $(releaseVersion)
      latest

It can get the dll file in docker:


And that's now, where the fun starts: as you see, I'm alreaddy running 'RUN ls -la /app' and within the build, it shows the files I'm looking for, but I don't see them when the container is running

You are only build on Docker@2 task not push, may i know if you add latter step to push the image to ACR? And what's the output RUN ls -la /app when you say it shows the files I'm looking for?  Does it contain the dll?

the push is done by just another task
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: push
    #containerRegistry: $(ACR_LOGIN_SERVER)
    repository: $(ACR_LOGIN_SERVER)/$(dockerImageName)
    tags: |-
      $(releaseVersion)
      latest
  displayName: 'Docker - Push'```

and yes, the RUN ls -la /app show the full content of the folder from where the files are copied in

You commented #containerRegistry: $(ACR_LOGIN_SERVER)  in the task above, please confirm if it's typo and let me know if the image is updated on ACR. Also, please show the RUN ls -la /app result, it should contain the dll files.

no, no typo. as 'containerRegistry' is for a service connection, which we are not using., thats why repository: $(ACR_LOGIN_SERVER)/$(dockerImageName)

Screenshot added to the first post
